# Showing $\int_0^\infty\frac {r} {x^2}e^{-x^2-\frac {r^2} {x^2}}dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2-\frac {r^2} {x^2}}dx$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

As part of a parameter integral problem, I need to show that given the function $$
\operatorname{F}\left(r\right) =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\left(-x^{2} - \frac{r^{2}}{x^{2}}\right){\rm d}x\,,\qquad \operatorname{F}\hspace{0.1mm}'\!\left(r\right) =
-2\operatorname{F}\left(r\right)\,,
$$
which amounts to what the title demands. However I cannot find a way to do so, either by integration by parts, substitution or anything else, even though it should be simple.

What am I missing $?$.

Comment: Substitute $u=\frac{r}{x}$

Comment: Incidentally, the larger problem this is a part of, in which you show $F^\prime=-2F$ and hence $F=F(0)e^{-2r}$, can be circumvented by evaluating $F$ directly, using [Glasser's master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem) and the fact that the integrand is even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a substitution $x\mapsto r/x$. It may be easier to follow if you write $y=r/x$ so the right-hand side transforms to $\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2/y^2-y^2}dy$.